Storage permission issue in android 5 to 13
I build my app whith native.vue and java. I'm trying to store and read data to internal storage of device. When i running this code in android 10 any permission request to user doesn't make.
In my manifest file i define:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

In my java file i have:
import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.widget.Toast;

With this code below, i show that i have not permission
public static boolean checkStoragePermissions(Context context) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
  // Android est 11 (R) ou supérieur
  Log.d("createDir", "Android est 11 (R) ou supérieur");
  return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
} else {
  // Inférieur à Android 11
  Log.d("createDir", "Inférieur à Android 11");
  int write = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  int read = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

  return read == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && write == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

}
So i try to get permission whith:
 public static boolean requestForStoragePermissions(Activity activity,
  ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> storageActivityResultLauncher) {
try {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.getPackageName(), null);
    intent.setData(uri);

    if (storageActivityResultLauncher != null) {
      storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    } else {
      activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true; // Requête réussie
  } else {
    Log.d("createDir", "Inférieur à Android 11");
    Log.d("createDir", activity.toString());
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        activity,
        new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        },
        STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    return true; // Requête réussie
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return false; // Erreur dans la requête
}

}
But when i run it in android 10 ,i don't get any dialog box in  phone.
Below my vue method.
  requestStoragePermissions() {  
        const activity = Application.android.foregroundActivity || Application.android.startActivity;
        let ctx = Utils.android.getApplicationContext();
        let execc = com.ecodev.Mifi.MyUtils.requestForStoragePermissions(activity, null);
        let exec = com.ecodev.Mifi.MyUtils.checkStoragePermissions(ctx);
        console.log('requestForStoragePermissions' + execc);
        console.log(exec);
    },

I read several post on the same subject and test this in vain.
Storage Permission Issue In android 10+ devices https://medium.com/@kezzieleo/manage-external-storage-permission-android-studio-java-9c3554cf79a7

Try to add this provide tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.
I think you need that to use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Android 10.
<application
   android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"   // Add this line
   .
   .
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name">


I already have it in my manifest.xml
